# AWS CLI: SES Configset Destination errors out

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I have a SES Configset created and trying to add SNS Event-Destination using CLI, But I get always this error,

```
[root@me]# aws --version
aws-cli/1.18.51 Python/2.7.5 Linux/3.10.0-1062.18.1.el7.x86_64 botocore/1.16.1
[root@me]# aws ses update-configuration-set-event-destination  --generate-cli-skeleton
{
    "ConfigurationSetName": "",
    "EventDestination": {
        "Name": "",
        "Enabled": true,
        "MatchingEventTypes": [
            "open"
        ],
        "KinesisFirehoseDestination": {
            "IAMRoleARN": "",
            "DeliveryStreamARN": ""
        },
        "CloudWatchDestination": {
            "DimensionConfigurations": [
                {
                    "DimensionName": "",
                    "DimensionValueSource": "linkTag",
                    "DefaultDimensionValue": ""
                }
            ]
        },
        "SNSDestination": {
            "TopicARN": ""
        }
    }
}

[root@me]# aws ses list-configuration-sets
{
    "ConfigurationSets": [
        {
            "Name": "my-ses-configset"
        }
    ]
}
[root@me]# aws ses update-configuration-set-event-destination --cli-input-json  {     "ConfigurationSetName": "my-ses-configset",     "EventDestination": {         "Name": "my-sns-destination",         "Enabled": true,         "MatchingEventTypes": [             "reject"         ],         "SNSDestination": {             "TopicARN": "<my SNS Topic ARN>"         }     } }

Unknown options: my-ses-configset,, EventDestination:, {, Name:, my-sns-destination,, Enabled:, true,, MatchingEventTypes:, [, bounce, ],, SNSDestination:, {, TopicARN:, <my SNS Topic ARN>, }, }, }, ConfigurationSetName:
```

What is wrong here? I am providing right SNS-topic-arn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to surround your input json with single quotes, otherwise the space separated strings in json will be interpreted as command-line arguments. That's why you got the `Unknown options` error message.

Comment: Thanks a lot @jellycsc, it worked for me. Even I referred https://awsclibuilder.com/home/services/ses, But it would have been AWS or doccumentation should have explicitly mentioned on quotes (might look silly but it helps).

Comment: @Krishna My pleasure. I'm glad it helps◡̈